# Finding the push certificate path within laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am struggling defining the path for my push certificate which I placed in the laravel folder structure in:

`config/ios-push-notification-certificates/certificate.pem`

In my APNS class I want to get the right path to use it for pushing then:

```
class APNS {
private $certificate = __DIR__ . "/ios-push-notification-certificates/production/certificate.pem";
(...)
}
```

But I get an error:

> syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'

How do I correctly reference the path?

I tried:

```
private $certificate = config_path() . "/ios-push-notification-certificates/production/certificate.pem";
```

but this returns the error

> expression is not allowed as field default value

Comment: You must initialize member variables to something that is static. You can define it outside of the class, `define('CERTIFICATE_FILE', __DIR__ . '/<path>/certificate.pem');` then `class APNS { private $certificate = CERTIFICATE_FILE;`

Answer (score 4):

For access to your certificat file `config/ios-push-notification-certificates/certificate.pem`
you can use `config_path($path)` directly like this :

```
private $certificate = config_path("ios-push-notification-certificates/certificate.pem");
```

this is equals to `/laravel_app_path_in_your_pc/config/ios-push-notification-certificates/certificate.pem` (absolute path)

Comment: While your answer may be correct, please try to add a sentence or two explaining the original mistake or your different approach. Code without any comment is normally not a good answer.

Comment: @ChristianKönig Ok, I did this